# How do I check if a User is using a mobile device in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, mobile, django-1.9

I'm using Django 1.9 with Python 2.7 and I'm trying to get my app to recognize if the user is browsing with a mobile device. I've tried django_mobile but it seems outdated for django 1.9 because there aren't even template_loaders to install the app, am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 6):

or you can use [django-user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) app. really good one. you also get the context in your template - among others important for rendering some ads depending on device

in view

```
request.user_agent.is_mobile
```

or in template

```
{% if request.user_agent.is_mobile %}
    Do stuff here...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: django-user_agents app saved my day. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the user agent string with

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

and then using [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents/) to parse that string.

**Example**

```
from user_agents import parse

ua_string = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
user_agent = parse(ua_string)
if user_agent.is_mobile:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MobileESP](https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp) library may help in this case. It is not Django-specific, but can be used with Django as a Python module. The [API page](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=53) details the detection capabilities, such as tiers (tablet / touchscreen smartphone) and specific platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are little wrong. To install `django_mobile` with `Django 1.9` you should update settings (I've described this in the [following PR](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/pull/66), not merged yet). It works fine for me.

Exactly, you should replace `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` with `loaders` and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` with `context_processors` in `TEMPLATES` dictionary. For more about template options, [read the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES)